# How to add a numeric value in a specific location for the whole column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a numeric column and I would like to add the digit 0 before the last 4 digits. The columns contain numeric values, but the values have different number of digits, some have 6 digits and some have 7. So counting the numbers from the beggining will be wrong, it has to be prior to the last for digits. So, for example:

Suppose I have a column, some numbers are:

```
123456
1234567
```

I would like the result to look like this, so 0 is always the number before the last 4 digits:

```
1203456
12304567
```

I don't know if it makes sense, let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use capture `()` the last four digits (`\\d{4}`) by adding the `$` to specify the end of the string and replace with the `0` followed by the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
df1$col1 <- as.numeric(sub('(\\d{4})$', '0\\1', df1$col1))
```

-output

```
df1$col1
[1]  1203456 12304567
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c(123456, 1234567)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: @AnoushiravanR it's okay.  We learn by trying hard initially and then it becomes easier

Comment: Yes it's true. Glad to see you there any way :)